# Unbroken en-dash

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I am trying to get an en-dash by using two '-' characters, but instead of appearing as one long en-dash symbol, I'm getting --. Any idea how I can get an unbroken en-dash?

Comment: Please post a minimal example and which engine and format you are using (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...) It could be a problem with ligatures, font, or just with your viewer. Zoom in, try a different viewer or print it.

Comment: You should get an unbroken endash by default. Are you using xelatex or special font package, etc.?

Comment: Try \textendash although I get an endash using two '-' characters. And, while we're on the topic, an even longer dash is produced by the \textemdash command

Comment: Apparently '--' doesn't produce an en-dash in math-mode; it works fine in text mode.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you perhaps trying to do this within math mode?  If, so that needs special attention:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Outside of math mode  13--17 works.

In math mode this does not work as the dashes represent a minus operation:
\[a = d\ 17--21\]

In math mode you need to:
\[a = d \hbox{ 17--21}\]
or if you have the amsmath pacakge:
\[a = d \text{ 16--19}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake, I was trying to get the en-dash from within math mode; it works fine in text mode.