# (Two hyphens != n-dash) even out of math mode

Tags: punctuation

I am not trying to do this in [math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25144/9549), and yet a pair of consecutive hyphens

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries\itshape
How are you?\\
{\emph --Bob}
\end{document}
```

are not converted to an n-dash. Why?

Comment: When you say `\emph --Bob`, the argument for `\emph` is the first hyphen (`\emph` takes an argument!).  The second hyphen is taken separately and not emphasized.  The two hyphens are not digested *together* by TeX as an en-dash, because your erroneous syntax caused Tex to digest one, then the other, separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct usage of `\emph` is `\emph{Bob}`. The command takes an argument!

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries\itshape
How are you?\\
{\emph --Bob} --test --\emph{Bob} \emph{--Bob}
\end{document}
```

you get what you want:

[image]